# How to assign a username and password for a particular port on a centos server

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos6

Currently i am running a centos server on AWS.
Any internet user can access this server by typing IP with port number on the browser.
I want to restrict it by putting some authentication check (adding a username and password)
Is this possible.... ?
If yes can you please suggest the solution.

Comment: you want to add password auth. what webserver are you running?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about what you want to achieve. If you want to restrict access by IP you can use the AWS instance's "firewall", i.e security groups. Read from the [AWS doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) which explains this very well. If this does not answer your question, please provide more details about your needs (is it ssh access, web app access, what is your infrastructure and access use cases etc)